# grouping and splitting data frame in R

Tags: r

The following is the promotion sales table listing products and group where the promotion was run and at what time.

```
   Product.code  cgrp promo.from   promo.to
1    1100001369    12 2014-01-01 2014-03-01
2    1100001369 16 37 2014-01-01 2014-03-01
3    1100001448    12 2014-03-01 2014-03-01
4    1100001446    12 2014-03-01 2014-03-01
5    1100001629 11 30 2014-03-01 2014-03-01
6    1100001369 16 37 2014-03-01 2014-06-01
7    1100001368    12 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
8    1100001369    12 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
9    1100001368 11 30 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
10   1100001738 11 30 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
11   1100001629 11 30 2014-06-01 2014-06-01
12   1100001738 11 30 2014-07-01 2014-07-01
13   1100001619 11 30 2014-08-01 2014-08-01
14   1100001619 11 30 2014-08-01 2014-08-01
15   1100001629 11 30 2014-08-01 2014-08-01
16   1100001738    12 2014-09-01 2014-09-01
17   1100001738 16 37 2014-08-01 2014-08-01
18   1100001448    12 2014-09-01 2014-09-01
19   1100001446    12 2014-10-01 2014-10-01
20   1100001369    12 2014-11-01 2014-11-01
21   1100001547 16 37 2014-11-01 2014-11-01
22   1100001368 11 30 2014-11-01 2014-11-01
```

I am trying to group the product.code and cgrp so that I can know all promotion for a product in a particular group and do further analysis.

I tried looping through the whole data.frame. Not efficient and buggy.

What is the efficient method to get this done.

[edit]
to get a multiple data.frame like the following

x=

```
   Product.code  cgrp promo.from   promo.to
3    1100001448    12 2014-03-01 2014-03-01
18   1100001448    12 2014-09-01 2014-09-01
```

y=

```
   Product.code  cgrp promo.from   promo.to
1    1100001369    12 2014-01-01 2014-03-01
8    1100001369    12 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
20   1100001369    12 2014-11-01 2014-11-01
```

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is.  You have some blank values in the 2nd column.  May be `split(yourdf, list(yourdf$Product.code, yourdf$cgrp), drop=TRUE)`.  Also  you may not need to `split` it if you need to summarise based on the grouping variables. FOr example, you can use `aggregate`, `dplyr`, `data.table` methods

Comment: @akrun, there is no missing values. look at row 4 and 18. The product code and cgrp are same for both. That is there was 2 promotion runs for the product code in that channel or group. I need to group like that so that I can proceed with analysis for that particular product and channel.

Comment: @drv can you show the `dput()` of your data? if it's too big `head(dput())` should work too

Comment: edited the question with the what is expected.

Comment: What is `16 11 16` etc after the first column?

Comment: they are multiple groups where the promotion was run. I have already written a function to ensure the correct filters are run on this multiple groups.

Comment: Is it part of the second column?

Comment: Try `library(splitstackshape);df1 <- as.data.frame(cSplit(df, 'cgrp', ' ', 'long')); split(df1, list(df1$Product.code, df1$cgrp), drop=TRUE)`

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the code I posted works for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` the 'cgrp' column and reshape the dataset to 'long' format with `cSplit`.  Then, `split` the dataset ('df1') by 'Product.code' and 'cgrp to create a `list` ('lst').

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(cSplit(df, 'cgrp', ' ', 'long'))
 lst <- split(df1, list(df1$Product.code, df1$cgrp), drop=TRUE)
 names(lst) <- paste0('dfN', seq_along(lst))
```

It may be better to keep the datasets in a `list`.  But, if you want as separate objects in the global environment, one option is `list2env` (not recommended).

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```